# Java: Have String Constant match its value

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there an easy way in Java 8 to have String Constants match its value, instead of doing this repetitively?

```
public static final String PATIENTID = "PATIENTID";
public static final String CREATEDDATE = "CREATEDDATE";
public static final String PREFIX = "PREFIX";
public static final String FIRSTNAME = "FIRSTNAME";
public static final String MIDDLENAME = "MIDDLENAME";
```

Comment: Could you use an enum? They have a `name()` method that gives you the string version of the name you use to declare them.

Comment: This is "code smell".  I suspect there's an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) here.  It would help if you could explain why you think you need to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an enum:

```
public enum Field {
    PATIENTID,
    CREATEDDATE,
    PREFIX,
    FIRSTNAME,
    MIDDLENAME;
}
```

and when you want to use one of your strings, you can use for example `Field.PATIENTID.name()`, which will return the string `"PATIENTID"`.